# tap with debounce does not go into subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I have an error for which I can't find an answer in google. My current code does not go into subscribe()

```js
// this one doesn't work and doesn't go into the subscribe()
 this._form.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      tap(data => this.service.setSaving(true)),
      debounceTime(500),
      takeUntil(this._unsubscribe$))
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log("inside subscription");
      .
      .
      .
    })
```

however, when I change the set setSaving function, into `console.log("something")` it works fine. Could someone explain this to me ?

```js
// this goes into subscribe()
 this._form.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log("something")),
      debounceTime(500),
      takeUntil(this._unsubscribe$))
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log("inside subscription");
      .
      .
      .
    })
```

and here is the setSaving method

```js
  setSaving(saving: boolean){
    this._savingSource.next(saving);
  }
```

Basically, all I'm trying to achieve is for the setSaving method to run before the debounceTime & subscription kicks in

cheers,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

silly me,

the issue wasn't with the syntax or anything rxjs related....

there was another subscriber to `saving$` which was restarting the `.valueChanges` subscription... basically it was unsubscribing from `.valueChanges` before it was able to go into the code above